# Wait with function completion untill the callback will come

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, callback, async-await

I am trying to implement mechanism, which will let me wait with function completion (in particular with return call) untill I will get some response inside a receiver. Receiver is waiting for response from some call from API or some other time consuming operation.

I was trying to do a while loop which is running on the boolean flag (volatile), which was supposed to be changed in the receiver, but the effect was that loop was running forever and the flag never changes.

Also I tried to implement a wait notify mechanism, but also, the wait function "blocks" the receiver to call notify.

EDIT: also I tried to use  BlockingQueue but with no luck here too.

I attach some example code with my implementation.

```
public String getRemoteInfo() {
    getInfo();
    while (!finished){
        Uninterruptibles.sleepUninterruptibly(200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }
    return globalResult;
}

private void getInfo(){
    service.getInfo(this); //"this" is an implementation of receiver
}

@Override
public void infoReceived(String result) {
    globalResult = result;
    finished = true;
}
```

Comment: may be interface can work..

Comment: @AbhayKoradiya  actually this method which is returning String should stay synchronous because of some other architectural reasons. I'm looking the way to delay completion of the method (even if it freeze the thread for couple seconds)

Answer (score 0):

This is a horrible way of doing it-  sleeping like this is called polling, and its bad for performance, battery life, etc.  The correct way to do it is to use a semaphore, and have the thread that wishes to wait wait on the semaphore, and the function that executes in the background signal the semaphore when its done.

Please note you should NEVER wait like this on the UI thread, as your app will go unresponsive while waiting.

Comment: Yes, I am aware that I should not do this on UI thread but eventually in this case the waiting will be happening on other , non UI thread. And my question is, how can I perform this waiting? Not if should I do it or not :) I will try though with the semaphore aproach, thanks